# Push to dataLayer on initial app load Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, analytics

I have an app which has GTM tracking. I'm currently checking when a route has taken place and pushing a page_view event to the dataLayer.

The problem I'm having is getting the dataLayer to push when the app loads initially. I have a back button which when clicked goes back to the home screen and fires an event but I can't get it to fire when the app loads initially. I can explicitly add the push event to the home component when it mounts, which will work but when I click the go back button it will fire twice.

Here's my code does anyone know how to get this to work when the app loads initially without duplicating the push?

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.path !== prevProps.path) 
    {
        this.routeChange();
    }
}
routeChange(){
   window.dataLayer.push({
        event: "page_view",
        url: this.props.path
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create your `history` object manually outside of the `Router` and listen to changes on that and also send an event directly when the file loads.

**Example**

```
import createBrowserHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

history.listen(location => {
  const { pathname } = location;

  window.dataLayer.push({
    event: "page_view",
    url: pathname
  });
});

window.dataLayer.push({
  event: "page_view",
  url: window.location.pathname
});

function App() {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      {/* ... */}
    </Router>
  );
}
```